# changeing state of one component from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

There are numerous guides how a state can be stored in the context and how this state can be changed from any of the components. These examples store the state and an update function in the context.

But is it also possible to store the state somewhere else and store only the update function in the context?

The motivation of this question is that storing the state together with an updater function can be seen as a redundancy, which could be avoided.

I tried already many things and read much about this. But it seems not to work for me. But I don't understand why not. It should be possible that one component provides a setter function in the context and another component just calls this setter function.

I am aware, that this will only work if there is exactly one instance of the component, that provided the setter function.

Comment: `<ZigZagContext.Provider value={this.state.setZigZag}>` https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider

Comment: @Chris Hamilton Thanks for the correction. This was indeed a mistake. But strangely it still does not work. So I corrected it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of one comment I found the answer.

The context in the following example is a function, which is visible in all components. Then in the component App there is a state and the setter. That setter is passed to the context. Once the setter is defined, it can be used by other components, such as the component GiveZag.

The good thing with this design is that the state and the way how it is updates is kept locally to where it belongs. It is often helpful to keep things as local as possible. Nothing of these details is revealed, except that there is a function, that can be called.

```
import React from 'react';

const ZigZagContext = React.createContext(
    (newValue) => {console.log(newValue)}
);

class GiveZag extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ZigZagContext.Consumer>
        { setZigZag  => (
          <button onClick={() => setZigZag("zag")}>make zag</button>
        )}
      </ZigZagContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {

  setZigZag(newValue) {
      this.setState({
          zigzag : newValue
      })
  };


  state = {
    zigzag: "zig",
    setZigZag: (newValue) => {this.setZigZag(newValue);}
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ZigZagContext.Provider value={this.state.setZigZag}>
        <h2>Current: { this.state.zigzag}</h2>
        <p>Click button to change to zag</p>
        <div><GiveZag /></div>
      </ZigZagContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Using the context is not always the best solution. This can be criticised in this case. The context enforces an unidirectional data flow.

Indeed the same can be achieved without the context mechanism. A solution that is simpler is the following code. This is not obvious and cannot be found so often in a web search. But it becomes clear when we keep in mind, that we have all features of JavaScript available. There is no need of using the context mechanism if not needed.

```
import React from 'react';

let ZigZagUpdater = (newValue) => {console.log(newValue)};

function GiveZag(props){
    return (
      <button onClick={() => ZigZagUpdater("zag")}>make zag</button>
    );
}

class App extends React.Component {

  setZigZag(newValue) {
      this.setState({
          zigzag : newValue
      })
  };

  state = {
    zigzag: "zig"
  };

  componentDidMount(){
      ZigZagUpdater = (newValue) => {this.setZigZag(newValue);}
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <para>
        <h2>Current: { this.state.zigzag}</h2>
        <p>Click button to change to zag</p>
        <div><GiveZag /></div>
      </para>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```