# React: state of states

Tags: reactjs

> React Hook "useState" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function

I understand *why* I am getting that message, but at the same time I think what I want should be achievable. Here's the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const children = useState([]);
  return (
    <div>
      {children.map((child, i) => (<Child child={child} />))}
      <button
        onClick={() => { children[1]([...children, useState(0)]); }}
      >
        Add
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Child(props) {
  const [state, setState] = props.child;
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="range"
        min="1"
        max="255"
        value={state}
        onChange={(e) => setState(e.target.value)}
      ></input>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want each `<Child>` to be in complete control of its state without having to declare a function of type `updateChild(i : Index, data)` then finding the right children in the list, etc. As this doesn't scale well with deep nested view hierarchies.

Is there a way to both:

- Keep the state in the parent (single source of truth)
- Allow children to mutate their own state

In a nutshell, I want to achieve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57144563/1949554) but with more than one child component.

Comment: Unless the child was also given access to the array and told its own index (i.e. got _all_ the arguments passed to the map callback) there's no way it can update the parent's array. Even then it would be mutating the array, which React wouldn't detect to re-render the parent, so only the child would be re-rendered. The correct solution is to pass a callback to inform the parent of changes, and it's unclear _why_ you don't want to do it.

Comment: > The correct solution is to pass a callback
In a way, that's exactly what I want to do `setState` is itself a callback. I'm trying to avoid creating a new one. I think it would simplify things. 

> there's no way it can update the parent's array
Since I'm passing a unique callback for each child, no index would be needed

Comment: I think, without registering the children somehow in a central array, it will not go. But that does not mean, that all your states have to go into that centraly storage or that you need an extra fuction. Just the setState functions have to go there. Have a look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74166211/changeing-state-of-one-component-from-another-component ! I think, this could help you.

Comment: Yes `setState` is a function, but to invoke it correctly you need to know the new value and the index at which it should be, and to use that to create a new version of the array with the new value at the appropriate index. So either that's defined in all of the children, which are also told their own indexes, and the parent loses control of its own state, or you keep it where the state is owned and expose a much simpler interface to the child, which can then just do `onChange={({ target }) => onChange(target.value)}`. And either way `children[1]([...children, useState(0)]);` isn't helpful.

Comment: > And either way children[1]([...children, useState(0)]); isn't helpful

I think we're potentially talking about different things. 
Clicking the button adds a new 'value' to the `children` state. That 'value' is, in itself, also a useState so eventually `children` state will look like `[(state, setState), (state, setState), (state, setState), ..., ...]`

Each one of these `setState` lambdas is then passed down to each respective child. There's no need to know the index.

Comment: here's an example of what I'm doing but using just one children: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57144563/1949554

See how an extra function is not needed here

Comment: Yes I can see what you're trying to do, an array of `[childXState, updateChildXState]` but that profoundly misunderstands what the hooks are doing. The example you've linked to works because the child gets the whole state of its parent. In this case you could give the child the whole state but then you also have to tell it which index it's at. And in both cases it's a bad idea from a coupling perspective.

Comment: It's not sending the whole state of the parent, the parent could have multiple `useState` which won't be passed down.

The reason I'm against using a lambda callback is, it doesn't scale well. What If I need to hoist my state 3 or 4 components up all of the sudden?

Comment: _"It's not sending the whole state of the parent"_ - and that's why it can't work. _"What If I need to hoist my state 3 or 4 components up"_ - then maybe the design was wrong to start with, but is that the problem you actually have? I suspect this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I've explained below the flaw in your current approach, which hopefully provides a much better mental model of the state of a function-based component, but whether that actually solves the underlying issue isn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate the problem with your current approach and why React won't let you do that, here's an ersatz implementation of `useState` that has approximately the same behaviour as the real version (I've left triggering a re-render as an exercise to the user and it doesn't support functional updates, but the important thing here was showing the underlying state of the `Parent` component).

```
// Approximation of useState
let parentStateIndex;
const parentState = [];
const useState = (defaultValue) => {
  const i = parentStateIndex;
  if (parentState.length === i) {
    parentState.push(defaultValue);
  }
  parentStateIndex += 1;
  return [parentState[i], (value) => parentState[i] = value];
}

const Parent = () => {
  parentStateIndex = 0;  // hack required to reset on each "render"
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);

  return (
    <>
     {state.map((child) => (
       <Child child={child} />
     )}
     <button
       onClick={() => setState([...state, useState(0)])}
     >
       Add
     </button>
    </>
  );
};

const Child = ({ child }) => {
  const [state, setState] = child;
  return (
    <input
      type="range"
      min="0"
      max="255"
      value={state}
      onChange={({ target }) => setState([target.value, setState])}
    />
  );
};
```

*(Note a bit of knowledge about the parent state has already crept into the child here - if it only `setState(target.value)` then the `[value, setter]` pair would be replaced by just `value` and other things would start exploding. But I think this way around gives a better illustration of what happens further down.)*

The first time the parent is rendered, the new array passed to `useState` is added to the state:

```
parentState = [
  [
    [],
    (value) => parentState[0] = value
  ],
];
```

All good so far. Now imagine the Add button is clicked. `useState` is called again, and the state is updated to add a second item and add that new item to the first item:

```
parentState = [
  [
    [
      [0, (value) => parentState[1] = value]
    ],
    (value) => parentState[0] = value,
  ],
  [
    0,
    (value) => parentState[1] = value,
  ],
];
```

This also seems to have worked, but now what happens when the child value updates to e.g. `1`?

```
parentState = [
  [
    [
      [0, /* this gets called: */ (value) => parentState[1] = value],
    ],
    (value) => parentState[0] = value,
  ],
  [
    /* but this gets changed: */ 1,
    (value) => parentState[1] = value,
  ],
];
```

The second part of the state is updated, which changes its type completely, but the first one still holds the old value.

When the parent re-renders, `useState` is is only called once, so the second item in the parent state is irrelevant; the child gets the old value `parentState[0][0]`, which is still `[0, () => ...]`.

When the Add button gets clicked again, because that's only the second time `useState` gets called on this render, *now* we get the new value that was intended for the first child, as the second child:

```
parentState = [
  [
    [
      [0, (value) => parentState[1] = value],
      [1, (value) => parentState[1] = value],
    ],
    (value) => parentState[0] = value,
  ],
  [
    1,
    (value) => parentState[1] = value,
  ],
];
```

And, as you can see, changes to either the first or second child both target the same value; they would not actually appear anywhere until the Add button was clicked again and they'd suddenly be the value of the third child.

For more on how hooks work and why the call order is so important, see e.g. [*"Why Do React Hooks Rely on Call Order?"* by Dan Abramov](https://overreacted.io/why-do-hooks-rely-on-call-order/).

---

So what *would* work? For the child to be able to correctly update its parent's state, it needs at least the setter and its own index:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);

  return (
    <>
     {state.map((child, index) => (
       <Child child={child} index={index} setState={setState} />
     )}
     <button
       onClick={() => setState([...state, 0])}
     >
       Add
     </button>
    </>
  );
};

const Child = ({ child, index, setState }) => {
  return (
    <input
      type="range"
      min="0"
      max="255"
      value={child}
      onChange={({ target }) => setState((oldState) => {
        return oldState.map((oldValue, i) => i === index
          ? target.value
          : oldValue);
      })}
    />
  );
};
```

But that means the parent no longer controls its own state, and the child has to know all about its parent's state - those two components are very closely coupled, so the boundary between them is clearly in the wrong place (and maybe shouldn't exist at all).

---

So what's the *correct* solution? It's the thing you didn't want to do, having the child "phone home" with an updated value and letting the parent update its state accordingly. This keeps the child decoupled from the details of the parent and its implementation correspondingly simple:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);

  const onChange = (newValue, index) => setState((oldState) => {
    return oldState.map((oldValue, i) => i === index
      ? newValue
      : oldValue);
  };

  return (
    <>
     {state.map((child, index) => (
       <Child child={child} onChange={(value) => onChange(value, index)} />
     )}
     <button
       onClick={() => setState([...state, 0])}
     >
       Add
     </button>
    </>
  );
};

const Child = ({ child, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <input
      type="range"
      min="0"
      max="255"
      value={child}
      onChange={({ target: { value } }) => onChange(value)}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this! Super appreciated. A couple of questions: Isn't the problem in your example that the `index` variable is shared by the `outter` and `inner` states?

Also, `onClick={() => setState([...state[0], useState(0)])} ` should be `onClick={() => setState([...state, useState(0)])}` to avoid the state nesting you show in the example.

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around it honestly. I'll take your word for it and use the callback approach even if I don't love it.

Comment: @frankelot 1. The shadowing was unhelpful, I've edited to distinguish the underlying `parentState` that the "hook" manages from the local variables in the components. 2. I don't have `[...state[0], useState(0)]` anywhere.

Comment: You're still using the same "set" lambda `(value) => parentState[i] = value];` for all `useState`s which mutate the same `parentState` array. Shoulnd't each `useState()` get their own state (array or value)

Comment: @frankelot the whole point of the `parentState` array is to illustrate (roughly) how the `useState` hook works behind the scenes. If I was to change that, such that each call was independent and the order didn't matter, then it would be completely useless as a tool to demonstrate the problem.