Why is React state variable not reinitialized on re-render
I created a simple React function component.
Here is how it looks:
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Parent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");

  console.log('Parent rendering ..');

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Parent Component</h1>
      <p>Data from Child: {data}</p>
      <button onClick={()=>{setData((new Date()).toDateString())}}>
        Click Me!!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Parent;

On click of the button I'm updating the state variable data and it causes a re-render. When it re-renders, I can see the console log getting printed, therefore const [data, setData] = useState(""); code portion would also must have executed. Then why/how does it show the updated value?

Because of the actual state underlying it. It doesn't have to (and doesn't) overwrite it with the initial default each time. See e.g. https://overreacted.io/why-do-hooks-rely-on-call-order/ (I wrote an approximation of useState in https://stackoverflow.com/a/74387327/3001761).


Why is state variable not reinitialized on re render

Because the initialState argument passed to the useState is only used for the initial render cycle, after that it's value is completely ignored.

Then why/how does it show the updated value?

The useState hook is still called each and every render cycle and returns the stable/memoized state and state updater function.
See useState Parameters:

Parameters

initialState: The value you want the state to be initially. It can be a value of any type, but there is a special behavior for functions.
This argument is ignored after the initial render.

If you pass a function as initialState, it will be treated as an initializer function. It should be pure, should take no arguments,
and should return a value of any type. React will call your
initializer function when initializing the component, and store its
return value as the initial state.




See also Returns:

Returns
useState returns an array with exactly two values:

The current state. During the first render, it will match the initialState you have passed.
The set function that lets you update the state to a different value and trigger a re-render.


Also, just think about it for a moment, if the state reset back to the initial value each render cycle it would make it rather useless. The idea is that it persists from render cycle to render cycle, whatever current value you set or update it to.


const [data, setData] = useState("");

By referring to the above statement, first of all, shall we ask a question ourselves ? Are we calling a function with an argument just to get the the same argument in return always. We are sure - certainly not!. As we know, each time when a function is called, it takes the given argument, and it executes some codes to return another value. Therefore we can say that the codes inside it generates the return value.
We know the general functionality of useState. It works as below.

On its first call, it returns a state variable with the value same as its argument.

On every subsequent call, it returns the latest value for the state.


By seeing the above two functionalities, can we not easily guess what should have been coded inside useState ?.
It must be something like the following for its first call:

create a new store and store the initial argument for later reference
return the stored value.

It must be something like this for its subsequent calls:

Refer to the stored value.
Process the state setters queued up.
return the new value.

Notes:
As we know, the state changes in the event handlers are not processed immediately, instead it will be queued up and processed from the queue when the render process will be followed on completion of the running event.
Now the obvious question remains is : how would the code differentiate the two invocations - first render and the subsequent renders ?.
The answer to this question is during the first call, the store or the state does not exist, therefore React will create a new store or state and return the same. For subsequent renders, the state will be already existing, and therefore it is referenced, updated with the state setters and returned.
Aside:
The state does not live inside a component. It lives in React. The component is just receiving the references when it is rendered or invoked. When the invocation is over, the variables local to the components are lost, still the state lives. And on the next render, the same state will get related with the same component. This is being done by React as part of its internal.
Citation:
Anatomy of useState

There doesn't seem to be any error in your code.The data variable is updated once you click on the button and you can display it like
console.log(`Parent rendering ..${data}`);

See updated value
